# 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command error in Android Studio terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, command, gradlew

Getting error - `'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command. operable program or batch file.`  inside Android Studio terminal.

Can anyone please tell why it's not recognizing **gradlew**

Comment: In my case I was trying `gradlew clean && gradlew assembleRelease` instead of `gradlew.BAT clean && gradlew.BAT assembleRelease`

Comment: Try using, `./gradle clean && ./gradle assembleRelease` worked for me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. gradlew command is available in your project directory. If you are trying to run this command from somewhere else it will throw error.
2. Also gradlew command package is automatically generated by Android studio when you create a new project. It will also prompt you to generate new gradle wrapper when you open the project.
3. you have to use `./gradlew` instead of gradlew , if you are using Mac or Linux

Comment: Thanks, the command worked when I traversed to my project's folder location from default 'sdk\platform-tools' location. But ./ didn't work, worked with only gradlew. Thanks a lot

Comment: chmod +744 ./gradlew

Comment: @ShirishHerwada I guess you are using Windows, that's why you don't require ./ .  In Mac or Linux it is usually required.

Answer (score 17):

It's under the Android folder, so you have to do cd Android first from your project root folder, then :

```
PS C:\code\my_app\android> ./gradlew signingReport
```

Answer (score 12):

in vscode do this step

1. go to your project directory
2. cd to android
3. type `./gradlew` in your terminal instead of gradlew
4. voila, it works for windows user

Answer (score 5):

Try using,
`./gradle clean`
`./gradle assembleRelease`
worked for me.

Comment: ./gradlew clean worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that you app's name is **video_compresser**, so when you open terminal on Windows PC(because I am trying this on Windows) it shows the prompt like this.

```
C:\Users\Nuwan\StudioProjects\video_compresser>
```

If you run `gradlew` from here you will get the below message

```
'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

so you have to go to **android** directory by typing `cd android` command from terminal.

then the prompt should be like this,

```
C:\Users\Nuwan\StudioProjects\video_compresser\android>
```

then type `gradlew` followed by other commands you need and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have debug.keystore file in
`PS C:\code\my_app\android>`
before you run
`./gradlew signingReport`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the powershell, use the Windows Command Prompt to run the command.

(This is an accidental finding. I used the visual studio code terminal to run the command `gradlew assembleRelease` to build the apk of a react-native project, but it outputs an error similar to above. I tried bash terminal, again failed to run. Out of curiosity, I used the Windows command prompt, then it worked. Hope this will help if other solutions are not working).

Answer (score 1):

If you use powershell, and the gradlew file is in the terminal current work directory, try .\gradlew instead of gradlew. Powershell don't run the command in the current work directory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

go to android directory by typing
"cd android" in terminal.

then the prompt should be like this,
PS C:\src\offx> cd android
PS C:\src\offx\android>

(//then type) ".\gradlew signinReport"
PS C:\src\offx\android> .\gradlew signinReport

Then you will get your sha keys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --alias=cos-android --password=abcd  --versionCode=00001 --versionName=00001 -- -- -- --packageType=bundle

cordova build android --prod --release --alias=cos-android --password=abcd  --versionCode=00001 --versionName=00001 -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

gradlew command is only available in your project directory or gradlew file location. If you are trying to run this command from somewhere else it will throw error.
so go to that particular location where gradlew file available

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
./gradlew signingreport
```

I didn't have JDK installed so, you have to do that as well if you see something like: "No JDK set and/or no java in path to be found".
After installing JDK just close and open again Android Studio and do

```
./gradlew signingreport
```

once more. You should be fine by now.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Flutter for to project folder under gradle folder and run the command `.\gradlew`

Answer (score 0):

If You Are Facing this error

- Where:
  Script 'H:<Your Folder><Your App Name >\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 389

Do This

in Your project Folder

cd android

./gradlew

./gradlew clean

Perfectly Working

Answer (score 0):

`gradlew` didn't work on my computer, though I'm a Windows user. `./gradlew` is worked successfully.

Answer (score -2):

I am using windows OS and have to run a Java project in IntelliJ. I used the command prompt in admin mode then it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31453285)